# JavaScript redirect to another JavaScript page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS class called "Cell.js" and I want to redirect to another JS Page called "Detail.js" when the user clicked on a button. But I do not know how to redirect AND pass a variable at the same time. 
I am working on a Pokedex (Pokemon List) and when the user clicks on the f.e. first Pokemon which has ID = 1, the ID should get passed to the Detail.js page where it shows more details of the selected Pokemon.

Cell.js code =

```
import React from 'react';
import './Cell.css';
import {ClassDeclaration as pokemon} from "@babel/types";

function Cell({ pokemon }) {
    let id = pokemon.name;
    return (
        <a href={"Detail.js?id= " + id } onclick="passID()">
        <div className="Cell">
            <div className="Cell_img">
                <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="Cell_name">
                {pokemon.name}
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
    );
}
function passID(){
    return(
        pokemon.id
        );
}
export default Cell;
```

And here is the target JS page "Detail.js":

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Detail.css';

const queryString = window.location.search;
console.log(queryString);
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const id = urlParams.get('id');

Detail(id)

function Detail(pokemon) {
    return (
            <div className="Detail">
                <div className="Detail_img">
                    <p>TEST</p>
                </div>
                <div className="Detail_name">
                    {pokemon.name}
                </div>
            </div>
    );
}

async function getPoke(id) {
    console.log(id);
    const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
    const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json);
}
export default Detail;
```

Detail.js is not done yet, I could test anything cuz I didn't know how to redirect and send the variable. Hope you can help me out
PS: I am very new to JS xD

Comment: `window.location.href = "Detail.js?fooParam=1arrayParam[foo]=2"`?

Comment: since you are using react i recommend that you should check react router for page navigations, however it is not necessary; if you using local files make sure you specify the location to avoid issues; for example in your case link to go to details should be "./Details.js/?id=1" and you do not need any passId function on click event; and inside details.js you could use the useEffect hook in the Details function to make the check for the url parameters

Comment: @mdln97 so i can just use the "href" in <a> ? cuz, when i click on the button, the URL changes to http://localhost:3000/Details.js/?id=bulbasaur but it does not load a blank new page (which should be the case) but it just reloads the main page (where the buttons are)

Comment: if you created your app using create-react-app or your app is a SPA then this will not work; therefore you should use react router to achieve that behaviour;

Comment: @mdln97 well it is an PWA app, but okay i will try it with react router, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Navigation in React will not happen that way!. React is intended for Single Page Application([SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)). `ReactDOM.render()` will load the container in which different views can be switched.

Recommended is [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start), but you could do this way for experiments.
You can pass any info as props to view component (in your case, id)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
 const [pageNo, setPageNo] = useState(1);
 let id = "Xyz"
 return (
   <div>
     <header>
       <span onClick={() => setPageNo(1)}>View1</span>
       <span onClick={() => setPageNo(2)}>View2</span>
       <span onClick={() => setPageNo(3)}>View3</span>
     </header>

     {loadView(pageNo, id)}
   </div>
 );
};
const loadView = (pageNo, id) => {
 switch (pageNo) {
   case 1:
     return <View1 id={id}/>;
   case 2:
     return <View2 id={id}/>;
   case 3:
     return <View3 id={id}/>;
 }
};

const View1 = ({id}) => <div>View 1 pokeman name = {id}</div>;
const View2 = ({id}) => <div>View 2 pokeman name = {id}</div>;
const View3 = ({id}) => <div>View 3 pokeman name = {id}</div>;
```

CSS

```
header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
header span {
  margin: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```