# React sending variable to JS page /function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to send a variable "pokemon" from the Cell.js to Detail.js.

Cell.js generates Buttons, each contains a pokemon and if clicked it should open a detailed page about the pokemon. So i need to send the pokemon (or pokemon id) to the Detail.js page. I am new to Javascript and i do not know how to send a variable to another js page or function.

Cell:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Cell.css';
import {ClassDeclaration as pokemon} from "@babel/types";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Detail from "../../Detail";

function Cell({ pokemon }) {
    let id = pokemon.name;
    return (
        <div className="Cell">
            <Link to={`/Detail/${pokemon.name}/`}>
            <div className="Cell_img">
                <img src={pokemon.sprites.front_default} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div className="Cell_name">
                {pokemon.name}
            </div>
            </Link>
        </div>

    );
}
export default Cell;
```

and the Detail code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './Detail.css';
import {ClassDeclaration as pokemon} from "@babel/types";

function Detail({ pokemon }) {

    return (
            <div className="Detail">
                <div className="Detail_img">
                    {pokemon.name}
                </div>
                <div className="Detail_name">
                </div>
            </div>
    );

}

export default Detail;
```

render:

```
const routing = (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/Detail/:pokemon" component={Detail} />
        </div>
    </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

PS.: I am using React and the PokeApi (https://pokeapi.co/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions to achieve that :

1. You can pass the whole `pokemon` object to your `Detail` Component. (as suggested by the way you wrote `Detail.js`
   But you need for that to pass the `pokemon` as a props inside the `Route`.

```js
<Route
  path='/detail/:pokemon'
  render={(props) => <Detail {...props} pokemon={pokemon} />}
/>
```

2. You can simply pass the pokemon's id to your `Detail` component.

```js
<Route path="/Detail/:id" component={Detail} />
```

that you would call like this :

```
<Link to={`/Detail/${pokemon.id}/`}>
```

and then in your `Detail` component you can get the id to make a new API call to only fetch one Pokemon :

```js
function Detail(props) {
    [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState(null);

    const fetchPokemon = () => {
        // let's assume an api call return result
        let result = // implement your api call
        setPokemon(result)
        setIsLoading(false)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPokemon(props.match.params.id)
    })

    if (isLoading) return <p>Loading</p>
    return (
        <div className="Detail">
            <div className="Detail_img">
                {pokemon.image}
            </div>
            <div className="Detail_name">
                {pokemon.name}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: i got "is not defined" errors from "result" and "match", could u tell me why?

Comment: because they are not defined, I did a typo on the params in `Detail` you have to get `match` from the props with desctructuring, if are not familiar with it, just pass props and access the id with `props.match.params.id`. But you still need to make an api call.

Comment: This would be the call for the api https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}  but how do i put it in result properly ?

Comment: Yes, what probem are you facing, you have the code of `getPoke` here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61522632/javascript-redirect-to-another-javascript-page. So `getPoke` would be the `fetchPokemon` method and the `result` would be you the `json` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have configured your Routes and the Details page is supposed to be rendered at `/Detail/:pokemon`

You can get the name of pokemon from match props like `props.match.params.pokemon`

```
function Detail({ match }) {

    return (
            <div className="Detail">
                <div className="Detail_img">
                    {match.params.pokemon}
                </div>
                <div className="Detail_name">
                </div>
            </div>
    );

}

export default Detail;
```

Comment: i just put my render/route in my post. i did what u suggested but i just get a blank page without.

Comment: `match.params.pokemon` is what you should be using then. Updated my answer

Comment: but how do i access the other "pokemon" variables? because pokemon has id, name, img,etc

Comment: See my answer I explained it @SkurSkurrrr